# Lenovo Thinkpad T530 - LCD has strong moire effect

Tags: thinkpad, lcd

I was just about to buy [Lenovo ThinkPad T530](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t530/) laptop, as the [reviews were speaking the best...](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Lenovo-ThinkPad-T530-2429-5XG-Notebook.78027.0.html) What was my surprise when I saw that the LCD has a strong moire effect! I mean, if you change viewing angles, you can sometimes see the pattern of the matte screen. It is especially visible on the blue window frame on the top of the screen.

It is not *extremely* visible, but it is disturbing - I noticed it at first sight. It is really surprising for a high-end laptop.

**Did you notice the same problem? Or is it just that piece? Do other similar laptops (E530, L530) have the same problem too?**

(PS: L430 has the problem too but much less intensive, T430 looks OK - but both are 14" only)

Comment: There's no guarantee that even two units with the same model will have the exact same display. Manufacturers swap them around all the time. Where did you see the unit you are talking about?

Comment: @James that's what I need to know - if the problem is consistent or whether I still have a chance to find a good piece. I saw it by the vendor last week.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't dirt/scratches on the screen or something? Or maybe a plastic screen protector? Also, could it have been running at the wrong resolution?

Comment: Your best bet might be to ask here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo/

Comment: James, the plastic screen protector is a god tip! I will ask the vendor about that, thanks! It would be stupid not to buy this laptop just because of this :-) Thanks

Comment: Citing discussion on **[notebookreview.com](http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo/730118-not-so-impressed-fdh-1920x1080-screen-t530.html)**: *"Most likely Lenovo no longer uses the AUO B156HW01 V.4 panel, which is known for its excellent quality."* Maybe we can see somewhere which panel is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have about 100 T530's in our operation -  30 times 1600x900 and 70 times 1920x1080. I have seen this issue 2 or 3 times. All the ones in which we have seen it were the 1600x900 version. We switched to the 1920x1080 version for the later batches we bought. In those later Lenovo's we haven't seen it. Luck I guess. The 1 HP system I have seen with the issue used the same brand/model LCD panel as the T530. (I have taken some apart to swap parts between broken machines that were not under warranty...)

I have also observed it occasionally on T500, T510 and T520.
My co-workers usually didn't notice it at all.
I had to point it out to them and even then most of them couldn't be bothered by it.

I have difficulties with my eyes and am VERY critical when it comes to displays.
This issue to me is visible but not really bad enough to bother me.

(I have more issues with clock-phases being out of sync, which I have never seen in an high-end business laptop, but which is common on low-end and consumer stuff.
And don't get me started about glossy screens.)

As far as I can tell this is incidental. I have seen it sometimes on other brands of high-end laptops as well. It all depends on the batch of the panels. Some have it, most don't.

if it really bothers you that much make sure you can test the laptop before you buy or have a free return deal with the vendor.

Comment: Dear Tony, thank you for the answer! I sympathize with you because I am also sensitive to things other people don't see. So you have seen 100 T530's and this issue was present only 2-3 times? So there is actually a *huge* chance that I'll found T530 *without* this issue?

Comment: @Tomas I figured you would be suffering from the same problem... With LCD's it isn't that bad, but back in the CRT days... I think you would be pretty safe considering the chances. But check with the vendor/shop first if you can return it, if it turns out the be problematic for you.

Comment: Thanks Tonny. And what about the "clock-phases being out of sync" problem? Did you observe this on current laptop LCDs? Did you observe it on T530?

Comment: I've never seen it on a recent (< 5 years) business laptop of any brand. Looks like the IPS panels that are mostly used today are pretty OK on that. This usually shows as a very light flicker in the bottom part of the display. It's most visible if the display shows alternating vertical full red (0xFF0000) and full green (0x00FF00) stripes. The edges of the stripes show faint flickering.

Comment: Tonny, do you please remember at which resolutions did you see the moire problem?

Comment: I couldn't quite remember but my colleague did. All 1600x900 for the T530. But I have to say I have also seen a HP 8750w (if I remember the type correctly) with a 1920x1080 panel that had it. I think the sample-size is too small for a statistically sound prediction.

Comment: Tonny, now I don't understand. First you said that you have seen it 2-3 times only and that most panels don't have it, and that you have 30x times 1600x900 T530 at work. And now you say that *all* 1600x900  T530 had it? How do these two informations match?

Comment: I meant "all the ones in which we have seen it were the 1600x900 version". We switched to the 1920x1080 version for the later batches we bought. In those later Lenovo's we haven't seen it. Luck I guess. The 1 HP system I have seen with the issue used the same brand/model LCD panel as the T530. (I have taken some apart to swap parts between broken machines that were not under warranty...) In fact I'm typing this on that HP that now uses the panel from a T530 that got fried by spilling beer over it.

Comment: :-) Thanks Tonny. Seems you have interesting work :-) BTW, you work by the laptop vendor?

Comment: @Tomas Sysadmin in a big international company. About 40% of my time is direct customer support on my local site with 500 users (hence dealing with office hardware). The other 60% is server/network infrastructure support for 137 sites (NorthWest Europe). Design for new sites, renovating existing sites and the planning/coordinating. And regular maintenance and small upgrades. 15 people in total, in 3 teams. I am one of the team-leaders. (The time doing customer support is mandatory to keep in touch with customer/business demands.)

Comment: Tonny, I have updated your answer using your various comments posted on this page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any LCD issues at all with mine, though I have the FHD display (1920x1080) and it is superb, (or at least the best I've ever seen on a laptop).

Of note, there are three different display panels offered in the T530, and all are LED backlit.

1. 1366x768
   2.1600x900
   3.1920x1080

I've had my T530 since February, and I really don't have any major issues with it.

The only two negatives I currently have are as follows:

1. The touchpad stops responding sometimes (driver issue)
2. The display hinges are so tight, that adjusting, and closing the display causes popping/creaking. (Though I can't complain, as this just means the hinges will stay tighter longer compared to other laptops.)

As for the keyboard, it is exceptional, and I have zero complaints.

The only thing I wish this laptop had was a caps key indicator, but I honestly don't mind it anymore.

Those are just my thoughts, I don't think you really can go wrong with these, but I haven't seen a model with a 1366x768, or 1600x900, so I can't tell you if the LCD panels have a moire effect.

Comment: Forgot to  mention in my own answer: Our mix is 30 times 1600x900 and 70 times 1920x1080.

Answer (score 0):

Through my work I have the T530 with FDH display.

Had a lot of problems tuning this screen, and it still is somewhat bad. What helped most is colour adjustment (there was too much of blue).

In Windows 8 scaling seems to be 125% by default, and this might be a catch. In 100% all seems quite fine, so I did a guess scaling is somewhat different on 1980x1080 then at 1900x1200 (my w500 has).

So I increased scaling by steps of 9%, and all looks a lot better. I ended up with 127%, and all looks fine now.

Hope this helps others. It is a workaround, the screen is still not 100%, booted in Linux, same problem (moire effect).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by FDH display? Please add the resolution information to your answer.