# ThinkPad T530 TouchPad stops responding

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad T530 running Windows 8 Pro X64.

I use two finger scrolling with my touchpad, and often scrolling will stop working for a few seconds, causing the cursor to just move erratically instead of scrolling like it should.

The other issue I have noticed is that the touchpad stops working altogether. Load shouldn't be an issue, but appears to affect the touchpad, even when CPU usage is below 20%. (below are my specs).

Of note, I am running the latest UltraNav driver from Lenovo's website, and it works better than the older versions of the driver.

Has anyone else had this issue? Lenovo has been of no help since February, this problem is getting really annoying, and this has been the first machine I have ever used with touchpad driver issues.

Specs: i7-3720QM 
NVS 5400M
FHD (1920X1080 panel)
4GB DDR3
WD Black 750GB

Ultranav driver version '16.2.19.9' from June 20th 2013.

Comment: +1 OMG I was just about to buy this machine! Don't know about yours, but I have observed different problem on T530, can you please have a look if you can see it? http://superuser.com/questions/621438/lenovo-thinkpad-t530-lcd-has-strong-moire-effect

Comment: I know that this is a very old question, but I just fixed this on a T530 running Windows 10 using this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixExternalMouseFreezingOnLenovoLaptopsWithSynapticsTouchPad.aspx - even though the symptoms aren't exactly the same, the fix is the same.